# IOS - second launch of my app going auto in background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

when I start my application from Xcode, the application works properly, but if I close and then open the app again, it goes into the background automatically without control. How can I fix this bug ?

Comment: Probably it will be a crash, Please check your device crash logs via Window -> Devices and Simulators -> View Device logs.

Comment: I tried from another macbook with another simulator importing the project in xcode and does the same thing

Comment: As @Natarajan said is a crash

Comment: Okay, but I don't have the log files, how can I retrieve them?

Comment: To see crash logs, Connect your iOS device to Mac and open Xcode, goto Window -> Devices and Simulators -> View Device logs.

Comment: if its a crash how it works  even with Xcode @Natarajan ?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan you will find a lot of interesting things about xcode

Answer (score 0):

There are some crash types those will not be happening when running the app via `Xcode`.

For example:
If the app launch takes too long, that app will be crashed. Basically it’s not a crash, but app needs to be launched quickly without delay which is expected by operating system.

So You need to make sure that you are not doing any heavy operations on Main Thread during app launch especially on below methods in `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

// Avoid heavy loads on main thread here
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

// Avoid heavy loads on main thread here
    return true
}
```

Also I received a crash a few years back when I tried to add an objective c struct to my NSObject class without allocating memory of struct variable. But this crash was unable to reproduce when I was running my app via Xcode and only happened when I launch the app without Xcode. So I made that struct variable as a pointer and did memory allocation as like `(BoothStructure*)malloc(sizeof(BoothStructure) * count)`, after that there was no crash.

So please analyze your crash using crash logs as well and check if it meets any one of above scenario.

**To check crash log of development build:**
Open Xcode -> Connect your iOS device which has/had the crashed app -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> View Device Logs

**To check crash log of production build(you should add your developer account in Xcode that is used to publish your app):**
Open Xcode -> Window -> Organizer -> Select your app from the list of apps -> Select crashes tab in segmented controller at top -> Select your build version.